# sizeof a function types in C

Tags: c, function, gcc, sizeof, c11

I have a some cases about `sizeof` operator, which is used with **function** types.

**Case 1** :  [[Live Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6hl5w31Amqi2svQR)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char func()
{
    printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(func())); //Ok. Output : 1
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    func();
}
```

Is `sizeof(func())` valid in C?

**Case 2 :** [[Live Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jx4kLjrBnSfetvxb)

```
printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(&func())); // error
```

It is not working. compiler give an error. Why?

**Case 3 :**  [[Live Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1JEiPgN7CZf5DBZD)

```
printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(&func)); //Ok. Output : 8
```

Here, Is `sizeof(&func)` equal to the sizeof the pointer?

Here, **case 3** working fine, where as **case 2** give an error. Why?

Comment: What output did you expect? What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve?

Comment: @cedrou, Michael Walz I have asked some questions in my post.

Comment: `sizeof(&func())` won't work here, because `func()` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @David Bowling But, sizeof(&func) work fine. why?

Comment: @DavidBowling Offhand, I'd think `sizeof(func);` would work, and I'd think `func` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle -- you can't take the address of the value returned from a function. `func` and `&func` are function pointers, and you can find their size using the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `sizeof` doesn't need an *lvalue* operand, but `&` does.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, no `sizeof` may not be applied to functions themselves. What would the result be? But it may well be applied to a function pointer. Function pointers are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement

```
printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(func()));
```

there is outputted the size of the expression (that is not evaluated) `func()`. As the return type of the function is `char` then the expression `func()` has the type `char` and `sizeof( char )` is equal to 1.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   1....

In this statement

```
printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(&func()));
```

there is an attempt to apply the unary operator `&` to a temporary object that is evaluated as the expression `func()`. You may not apply the operator to a temporary object.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 1 **The operand of the unary & operator shall be** either a function
>   designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or **an lvalue**
>   that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared
>   with the register storage-class specifier.

for comparison consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * func()
{
    static char i = 0;

    printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(&*func()));

    return &i;
}

int main(void)
{
    func();
}
```

In this program the function returns pointer to the lvalue `i` with the static storage duration. So applying the unary operator `*` you will get the lvalue. So you may apply the operator `&` in this case.

The program output will be

```
sizeof func = 8
```

In this statement

```
printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(&func));
```

there is evaluated the operator sizeof for a function pointer of the type `char ( * )( void )`. Again according to the quote from the C Standard the operator `&` may be applied to a function designator.

Take into account that the function definition shall look like

```
char func( void )
           ^^^^ 
{
    printf("sizeof func = %zu\n", sizeof(func())); //Ok. Output : 1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The operand of `sizeof` can have two forms:

- A paranthesized *type name*, e.g. `(char)`, `(int)`, `(struct mystruct)`, ...
  The result is the storage size of the named type.
- An expression. The result is the storage size of the type the expression *would* evaluate to (but it isn't evaluated).

None of your examples is a *type name*. The *type name* for your function would be `char (void)`. So all your parantheses are superfluous.

In your first example, you have `sizeof func()`. Evaluating `func()` would return a `char`, therefore the result is `1`.

In your third example, you have `sizeof &func`. Evaluating `&func` would give you a function pointer and the size of a function pointer is `8` on your machine.

The second example is just wrong, `&func()` is not a valid expression. You can't take a pointer to a function call. In standard terms, `func()` is not an *lvalue*, which is required to apply `&`.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(type)` returns the size in bytes of the object representation of type.

`sizeof(expr)` returns the size in bytes of the object representation of the type that would be returned by expression, if evaluated.

**case 1**

`func` is a function that returns a value of type `char`. So `sizeof(func())` is the same as `sizeof(char)`, which is `1`

**case 2**

`&func()` is not a valid expression (you are trying to get the address of the return value of the function, which is undefined)

**case 3**

`&func` returns the address of the function `func`, which is a pointer. On a 64-bits system, `sizeof(&func)` will be the size of a pointer, that is `8`. It will be `4` on a 32-bits OS.

Comment: Agree will all except "On a 64-bits system, sizeof(&func) will be the size of a pointer".  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721324/2410359)

Comment: @chux can you please elaborate ? Why would `sizeof(&func)` not the size of a pointer ?

Comment: C does not specify that the size of a pointer to a _function_ must be the same as the size of an pointer to an _object_.   True, it is common that they are the same.  See [separate address spaces for code and data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358887/2410359), [guaranteed about the size of a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941793/2410359)  Highly portable code doe not assume theses pointers are the same size.

Comment: What about `sizeof(func)`? I get `1` as result, but can't figure out why

Comment: @RafaelEyng It's normally forbidden but GCC returns 1. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666392/12688015